# Resource Requirements for MS Exchange 2010 Transport Rule

Tags: exchange

We want to use the Transport Rule to automatically add confidentiality disclaimers to all outgoing emails. The server is quite old, and we’re afraid the rule will eat resources and the system performance will go down.

How much resource does MS Exchange 2010 use for Transport Rule?

There are 25 000 users.

The existing system characteristics are:

**Exchange 2010 SP1 HUB Transport Server**
CPU:  Intel X5560 (2 Processors) 2.80 GHz
RAM: 40 Gb
HDD: 135 GB

**Exchange 2010 SP1 Mailbox Server**
CPU:  Intel X5560 (2 Processors) 2.80 GHz
RAM: 40 Gb
HDD: 135 GB + 2Tb Storage

**Exchange 2010 SP1 EDGE Server** 
CPU:  Intel X5560 (2 Processors) 2.80 GHz
RAM: 16 Gb
HDD: 135 GB

Comment: You have 25,000 users on a single mailbox server?

Comment: No, it has a replication server. I didn't write it here not to overload you with information. But each of the above server have duplicate replications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How much resource does MS Exchange 2010 use for Transport Rule?

This is difficult at best to answer.  Microsoft doesn't publish a guide on this other than to say "the more transport rules you have the more cpu and ram will be utilized".

With 25,000 users per mailbox server and only 40GB of RAM I'm really shocked you aren't overloaded already, but based on the HDD space they must be very small mailboxes.

To truly calculate this will be unique per environment.  You have to consider mail flow volume, time of day, current cpu/memory load, etc.

To be honest, you may be overthinking it.  Put the disclaimer rule in place and monitor performance.  The impact of a simple disclaimer rewrite is pretty negligible from what I've seen over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2010 SP1? Really? I would upgrade the server to SP3 as soon as possible. All email goes through the transport role anyway, so adding the rule isn't going to take much resources. However for the number of users I would be looking at a third party tool to build the signatures - Exclaimer or CodeTwo would be the two I would look at.